# Div positioning over another div

Tags: css, image, position

I am trying to place a div which contains a clickable picture on a div which contains a background. However, this keeps happening:

http://gyazo.com/2144dfe91b46898e125787b2f5249542

It goes below the image and I don't understand why.

here is my code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SlammedPK</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="dragonclaws.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    <style type"text/css">
    #title{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #forum{
        height:10%;
        width:10%;
        background-image:forum.png;
        display:block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
</body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="title" style="position:relative" alt="title">
    <img src='fulltitle.png' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
    </div>
    <div id="forum" style="position:absolute" alt="forum">
    <A HREF="http://google.com"><IMG SRC="forum.png" ALT="forum"></A>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you could help that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your format for the background image is incorrect, you need `background-image: url(forum.png);` and the same thing for `#title`. I'm not sure why you give it a background image when you also have an `img` within it though

As for your issue, you need to give `#container` `position:relative;` or `position:absolute`. Absolutely positioned elements have to be a child or a relatively positioned parent

Comment: I added that into the forum css and i added 'background-image:fulltile.png;' to the #title. But nothing changed?

Comment: @FinnBeckett-hester I'm dumb, I updated my solution. It should fix your problem now

Comment: @FinnBeckett-hester If an answer satisfies your question, you can mark the check mark to the left of the answer to show it is correct and show the question has been answered

Answer (score 0):

I made this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2c7eQ/

Make both `#forum` and `#title` are `position: absolute`

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="title">
    div1
    </div>
    <div id="forum">
    div2
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title{
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: blue;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
}
#forum{
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: green;
        height:10%;
        width:10%;
}
```